# Can't run executables after Revo Uninstaller cleaning the registry

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

I was trying to remove MSDN Library-January 2002 by using Revo Uninstaller. I allowed it to delelet those `leftover registry entries`(my fault, i should be more careful and don't do that). Now my machine is almost unaccessible, cannot open that Revo Uninstaller to recovery, cannot open Windows Explorer, cannot run CMD command from run, all executable shortcuts are not working anymore.

I guess I have to reinstall everything but how can I get my data out of the machine? It is a Dell laptop with Windows XP. I am afraid if I restart my machine, my machine will not come back anymore.

Comment: Not a programming question. But as a friendly tip, just plug the hard-drive into another computer and extract your data. Or boot it up from a Linux LiveCD and move the data somewhere over the network, or to an USB memory or something, if it fits

Answer (score 3):

It stores [deleted uninstall entries](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_remove_entry_command.html) here, look in that folder and see if its made a .reg file to undo its "Registry Cleaning".

Failing that, System Restore.

Comment: There is no such backup folder, no any .reg files, what I download is the professional version

Comment: Try the EXE File Association Fix here; http://www.dougknox.com/xp/file_assoc.htm then see if you can get into it and make it undo whatever it did. If you can't try a system restore.

Comment: @Alex you are saving me days time. Now the Revo Uninstall is launched from Task Manager -> cmd -> Revo Uninstall. It is restoring now. how can I give you more credits? really really appreciate your helppppppppppppppppppppppppp!!

Comment: I didn't realize it deleted my 216923 items from registry

Comment: haha, it works. happy day today. thank you! Alex

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a recovery tool like [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html) or [Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download) to boot into the PC (These tools have their own OS).
2. Then copy over the data to a backup drive or portable Disk.
3. Format C:\ (Windows Drive) and re-install Windows.

By the way this question belongs on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/)